# Set specific color to specific date in calendar generated using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

I have generated a calendar using codeigniter calendar library and passed data array to highlight specific dates. Which is working fine. But I want to highlight some dates differently. E.g. default highlighted dates have green color. But on some dates I want to assign blue color.

Here is the code :

```
$prefs = array();
$this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM package_mst
        WHERE status=1
        AND departure_date>='" . date("Y-m-d") . "' 
        HAVING departure_month='$selected_month'  
        AND departure_year='$selected_year'";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$total_records = $query->num_rows();
$data = array();
if (!empty($total_records)) {
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $data[$row['departure_day']] = base_url('package/search_by_month/' . $selected_month . '/' . $selected_year);
    }
}
$calendar_html .= $this->calendar->generate($selected_year, $selected_month, $data);
echo $calendar_html;
```